# How can I use a bamboo plan variable in a script task?

Tags: bamboo

I have defined in my bamboo plan a variable (`BAMBOO_TEST_VAR`) that I'd like to reuse in a particular script but I can't seem to figure out how to make it visible to that script.

[image: Bamboo Plan Variables Configuration]

If I just reference that variable from the script it merely prints the variable as empty.

```
27-Oct-2020 23:34:00    TEST JOB
27-Oct-2020 23:34:00    bamboo.shortJobName = 
27-Oct-2020 23:34:00    BAMBOO_TEST_VAR=
```

[image: Bamboo Script Configuration]

And if I provide it as input to the `Environment variables` field it just renders with the value I give in that field taken as a literal, not to the plan variable I was hoping it would evaluate to.

```
27-Oct-2020 23:36:57    TEST JOB
27-Oct-2020 23:36:57    bamboo.shortJobName = 
27-Oct-2020 23:36:57    BAMBOO_TEST_VAR=$BAMBOO_TEST_VAR
```

[image: Configuring from Environment variables field]

How can I reference the plan's environment variable directly from a script task without passing it down through arguments or something of the sort. What aspect or bamboo detail am I ignorant of that would have informed me that what I'm attempting is not possible or not supported because of reason XYZ?

Answer (score 0):

So the trouble was I didn't scope the variable appropriately. What did it in the end was

```
${bamboo.BAMBOO_TEST_VAR}
```

[image: proper plan variable usage]

Turns out if I slowed down and looked at the bamboo page more carefully I would have noted the help breadcrumbs they left around. Copying that help text here, emphasis mine:

> Variables substitute values in your task configuration and inline scripts. If a variable name contains any reference to a password, like "password", "sshKey", "secret", or "passphrase", its value will be masked with "********".
>
> For tasks configuration fields, **use the syntax ${bamboo.myvariablename}**.